# Spain study visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, spain, study

My son received a Spanish study visa type D for 90 days on 27 July 2016 (visa valid from 27/7/2016 to 8/11/2016). Consulate said to apply for residence visa after arrival in Spain. We plan to reach Spain on 11/9/2016 since his semester will start on 16 September 2016. I want to know is it OK to enter Spain (it will be more than one month after visa granted).

Is there any rule that requires entry into Spain within one month of visa grant?